Word table – Issue with setting column width to a low value in a VBA-generated table
Environment: Windows 10 Pro 64 bit, Word 2019.
Context: For certain uses, I like to format Word tables in such a way that columns containing data are separated by empty "divider" columns of a small width (0.1 to 0.2 cm), and likewise in respect of rows; and I do not want to use cell margin. So a 5-column table would actually have 9 columns, as depicted below:
Example table

If I create the table manually, I can easily set the width of the divider columns to a low value, say 0.15 cm (with a minimum of 0.04 cm) using the table layout menu, subject to having first set cell left and right padding to 0.
But, if I generate the table via VBA code, the code produces an error (error # 4608 – value out of range) as soon as it attempts to set the width of a column to less than 0.28 cm (notwithsanting that cell padding has been set to 0). Likewise, if I generate the table via VBA code with cell padding set to 0 and without changing column widths and then try to manually set a column width using the Word table layout menu, it won't let me go to less than 0.28 cm.
The problem does not seem to arise from the VBA column width instruction itself. Indeed, if I first create the table manually (with cell padding manually set to 0) and then run simple code to set the width of a column to 0.1 cm, it works fine, e.g.:
Dim TBL As Table
Set TBL = Selection.Tables(1)
TBL.Columns(2).Width = CentimetersToPoints(0.1)


If I first create the table manually (again with cell padding set to 0) and then run simple code that also sets cell padding to 0 (even though the manually created table already has that feature) and sets a column width to 0, it works as well:
    Dim TBL As Table
    Set TBL = Selection.Tables(1)
    With TBL
        .LeftPadding = CentimetersToPoints(0)
        .RightPadding = CentimetersToPoints(0)
    End With
    TBL.Columns(2).Width = CentimetersToPoints(0.1)

But if I create the table via VBA, the error arises:
    Dim TBL As Table
    ActiveDocument.Tables.Add Range:=Selection.Range, NumRows:=3, _
        NumColumns:=4, DefaultTableBehavior:=wdWord8TableBehavior, _
        AutoFitBehavior:=wdAutoFitFixed
    Set TBL = Selection.Tables(1)
    With TBL
        .LeftPadding = CentimetersToPoints(0)
        .RightPadding = CentimetersToPoints(0)
    End With
    TBL.Columns(2).Width = CentimetersToPoints(0.1)

It seems that somehow the table responds differently in connection with column width depending on whether cell padding has been set manually or via VBA code. If I create the table via code, then sets the celle padding to 0 manually and then use code again to set the column width, it works. But it does not if the cell padding has been set via code.
Does anyone have an idea as to why this error occurs, and a solution for it?
Thanks.

Why are you making it so complicated? No need to mess around with extra unnecessary rows and columns. Just create a table style with thick white internal borders.

Have you tried setting the text of such columns to a low value (such as 1 pt)?

Try:
Sub Demo()
    Dim TBL As Table
    Set TBL = ActiveDocument.Tables.Add(Range:=Selection.Range, _
        NumRows:=3, NumColumns:=4, AutoFitBehavior:=wdAutoFitFixed)
    With TBL
        .LeftPadding = 0
        .RightPadding = 0
        With .Columns(2)
          .PreferredWidthType = wdPreferredWidthPoints
          .PreferredWidth = CentimetersToPoints(0.1)
        End With
    End With
End Sub


Thanks Macropod! This works initially. But, once the table has been created in this manner, if you try to change the width of one of the divider columns using the table layout menu, say to make it 0.15 cm instead of 0.1 cm, the width automatically goes to its minimum of 0.28 cm and won't go to less.

Well, you asked for a solution to your VBA problem, which is what I gave you. If You want a different column width when the table is created, change the code accordingly (e.g. use an inputbox to solicit the width if you want to vary it). Otherwise, it isn't a programming issue.
